# run coffeescript from *.coffee file in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, coffeescript

I install "Mindscape Web Workbench" visual studio extensions and add LessCoffee reference from Nuget.

In my page, I wrote those codes and it is running.

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script src="http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/extras/coffee-script.js"      type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script type="text/coffeescript"> 

    @fonksiyon = () -> alert "I knew it!"

    @myalert=(myText)-> alert myText

    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <input type="button" id="deneme" onclick="fonksiyon()" value="Deneme" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="Button1" onclick="myalert('yazi veya uyari')" value="Deneme" />    </asp:Content>
```

I want to run the same code from "Coffee1.coffee" so I wrote this:

in CoffeeScript.coffee

```
    @fonksiyon = () -> alert "I knew it!"

    @myalert=(myText)-> alert myText
```

In Asp.net Page:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script src="http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/extras/coffee-script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="CoffeeScript1.coffee" type="text/coffeescript"></script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <input type="button" id="deneme" onclick="fonksiyon()" value="Deneme" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="Button1" onclick="myalert('yazi veya uyari')" value="Deneme" />
</asp:Content>
```

But this code doesn't work.

CoffeeLess add web.config:

```
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*.coffee" type="DotSmart.CoffeeScriptHandler, LessCoffee" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="*.less" type="DotSmart.LessCssHandler, LessCoffee" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="*.less.css" type="DotSmart.LessCssHandler, LessCoffee" verb="*" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*.coffee" type="DotSmart.CoffeeScriptHandler, LessCoffee" verb="*" name="DotSmart.CoffeeScriptHandler" />
      <add path="*.less" type="DotSmart.LessCssHandler, LessCoffee" verb="*" name="DotSmart.LessCssHandler" />
      <add path="*.less.css" type="DotSmart.LessCssHandler, LessCoffee" verb="*" name="DotSmart.LessCssHandler2" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

I controled it with Firebug and  return this error:

'SyntaxError: reserved word "function" on line 4' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]
[Break On This Error]
Filtered chrome url chrome://firebug/content/net/spy.js

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note that doesn't answer your question at all. I'd recommend using the Mindscape Web Workbench for LESS now. I used Duncan's solution before then and it was excellent, but the Workbench has highlighting, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the httpHandler to serve up *.coffee files the they get converted to JavaScript on the server, hence your client-side script tag should actually specify JavaScript:

```
<script src="CoffeeScript1.coffee" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the information may be helpful in your work.

http://blog.dotsmart.net/2011/06/30/lesscoffee/